# Cannot find saved CSV or TXT file on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, export-to-csv, fileoutputstream

I have three `ArrayLists` that I would like to save to a CSV file and then retrieve to email them through an app I am building. Two of the lists contain double values and the last one contains timestamps.

This is how I attempt to save them to a CSV file (saw on YouTube):

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.append("Timestamp,Mass,Change in Mass");
for(int i = 0; i < mass_list.size(); i++){
     data.append("\n"+String.valueOf(timestamp_list.get(i))+ ","+String.valueOf(mass_list.get(i))+","+String.valueOf(mass_roc_list.get(i)));
}
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("scale.csv", Context.MODE_APPEND);
out.write((data.toString()).getBytes());
out.close();
```

I basically scroll through the lists and append values to a file using commas to separate them. This is how I attempt to retrieve it:

```
String filename="/scale.csv";
File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.scaleapp.fileprovider", filelocation);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {"MY_EMAIL"};
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Scale Data");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the body");
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
// the attachment
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

I am basically trying to attach the file in an email. Here is a snippet of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<provider
     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="com.example.scaleapp.fileprovider"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true"
     android:exported="false">
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
 </provider>
```

And `provider_paths.xml`:

```
<external-path name="scale" path="."/>
```

The code runs and does not crash. However, when I try to send the data in an email, it says that "cannot attach an empty file." I am confused about why the file would be empty.

The issue could be me incorrectly saving as a CSV. However, I tried changing the extension to `.txt` and the same thing happened. I am unsure if its the file-saving or file-retrieving code that is not working. I appreciate any help and will provide clarification if needed.

Comment: The `openFileOutput()` method opens a file in your app's internal storage. `filelocation` in your second snippet points to a file in external storage. Where do you mean for the file to be?

Comment: Also, please don't repeat questions. When you edited your previous one to explain why the answer didn't work, it got bumped to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I thought it would be more appropriate for one question to be more about sending email and another to save a file. My bad. I just want to temporarily save a file (I guess internal would be easier) so that I can send it as an attachment. Afterward, it can be deleted.

Comment: No worries. It's just that, if users started posting new questions as follow-ups to ask why a previous answer didn't work just because of a minor issue, we'd be absolutely flooded. Anyhoo, I definitely agree that internal is the way to go. You wouldn't need the permission for external storage, and starting with Android Q, it's going to be extra hard to use external, anyway. To get you to internal, first change that `<external-path>` to `<files-path>`. Then just change your retrieve to use `new File(getFilesDir(), "scale.csv")`, instead of `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()...`

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues with that, or if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much for your help. I was able to resolve my problem!